How do I destroy a part when it touches another part?
I'm trying to script a Roblox game.
The aim for now is when I click the "AttractButton" the Object should attract towards player's location and stop 4 studs away. On the other hand, clicking the "RepelButton" should repel the Object a certain distance away. That works fine. the Object collides with another part that's called Orb and stops in its tracks. However, I'm trying to make the Object disappear by the destroy() function but it's just not working no matter how much debugging I do. Can someone help me?
This script is in the StarterGui:
    local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local CollectionService = game:GetService("CollectionService")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local controlGui = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("ControlGui")
local attractButton = controlGui:WaitForChild("AttractButton")
local repelButton = controlGui:WaitForChild("RepelButton")

local attractMode = false
local repelMode = false

local cooldownTime = 2
local lastInteractionTime = {}
local velocity = 10 -- studs per second

-- Function to handle the attract button click
local function onAttractButtonClick()
attractMode = true
    repelMode = false
    print("Attract mode enabled")

-- Visual feedback for button click
    attractButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(200, 200, 200) -- Change to a different color
    wait(0.1) -- Wait for a short delay
    attractButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255) -- Revert to original color
end

-- Function to handle the repel button click
local function onRepelButtonClick()
    attractMode = false
    repelMode = true
    print("Repel mode enabled")

    -- Visual feedback for button click
    repelButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(200, 200, 200) -- Change to a different color
    wait(0.1) -- Wait for a short delay
    repelButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255) -- Revert to original color
end

attractButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onAttractButtonClick)
repelButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onRepelButtonClick)

-- Function to perform raycast check
local function raycastCheck(startPos, endPos)
    local direction = (endPos - startPos).Unit * (endPos - startPos).Magnitude
    local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
    raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
    raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = {player.Character}

    local result = workspace:Raycast(startPos, direction, raycastParams)
    return result
end

-- Function to move object to final position with collision checking
local function moveObject(target, finalPosition)
    local connection
    local function onHeartbeat()
        local currentPosition = target.Position
        local direction = (finalPosition - currentPosition).Unit
        local deltaTime = RunService.Heartbeat:Wait()
        local newPosition = currentPosition + direction * velocity * deltaTime
        local result = raycastCheck(currentPosition, newPosition)

        if result then
            target.Position = result.Position - direction * 1 -- Stop just before the obstacle
            connection:Disconnect()
            return
        elseif (currentPosition - finalPosition).Magnitude < 1 then
            target.Position = finalPosition
            connection:Disconnect()
            return
        end

        target.Position = newPosition
    end

    connection = RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(onHeartbeat)
end

-- Function to handle mouse button click
mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    local target = mouse.Target
    if target and target:IsA("BasePart") and CollectionService:HasTag(target, "attractable") then
        local currentTime = tick()
        local lastTime = lastInteractionTime[target]

        if lastTime and (currentTime - lastTime) < cooldownTime then
            print("Cooldown active. Please wait.")
            return
        end

        lastInteractionTime[target] = currentTime

        local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
        local humanoidRootPart = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        local targetPosition = humanoidRootPart.Position

        local offset, finalPosition
        if attractMode then
            offset = (target.Position - targetPosition).Unit * 4
            finalPosition = targetPosition + offset
        elseif repelMode then
            offset = (target.Position - targetPosition).Unit * 20
            finalPosition = target.Position + offset
        end

        finalPosition = Vector3.new(finalPosition.X, target.Position.Y, finalPosition.Z) -- Keep Y the same

        moveObject(target, finalPosition)
        print(attractMode and "Object attracted" or "Object repelled")
    end
end)

This is the code in Object:
local object = script.Parent -- Assuming the script is directly inside the Object part
local orb = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("Orb") -- Assuming the orb is named "Orb" and is a separate part in the Workspace

local function onHit(otherPart)
    if otherPart == orb then
        object:Destroy()
    end
end

object.Touched:Connect(onHit)


Have you tried to print the orb variable to make sure it isn't null and if so try to add some print statements in the object to identify what part of the script doesn't get triggered.

In your code, you compared the object to an undefined parameter, which will return false. First check if otherpart is a part, then check if it has the same name as the orb, and then destroy object.
Use a basic system like this:
--server script
local function onHit(otherpart)
      if otherpart:IsA("BasePart") then
         if otherpart.Name==orb.Name then
            object:Destroy()
         

